# How to restore the state of tf.train.AdamOptimizer from a checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to restore the state of tf.train.AdamOptimizer from a checkpoint in Tensorflow in order to start again the training on another dataset without resetting the state of the optimizer. I know that a solution is the one proposed in [Saving the state of the AdaGrad algorithm in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547198/saving-the-state-of-the-adagrad-algorithm-in-tensorflow). However, the proposed solution works only by using tf.train.import_meta_graph, but I don't want to use that method. If I try to follow that solution, I obtain an empty list when I call tf.get_collection("train_step"). Would you suggest me another solution?

Thank you.