# How to obtain an optimizer object from a restored tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization

I created a tensorflow model with adam-optimizer using

`tf.train.AdamOptimizer(..., name='AO').minimize(...)`

After I stored the model and restored it from the model file, I would like to use the optimizer to minimize a different variable set. My question is how do I obtain the optimizer object named `'AO'`?

Answer (score 0):

If your optimizer is used like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

The optimizers state is saved by default, when calling:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver().save()
```

And is to be restored as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelfile+ '.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
train_step = tf.get_collection("train_step")[0]
```

More on saving a checkpoint ([here](http://www.seaandsailor.com/tensorflow-checkpointing.html))
Also a similar problem has been discussed on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5595) and on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547198/saving-the-state-of-the-adagrad-algorithm-in-tensorflow).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, I want to obtain the 'optimizer' object, not the operation returned by the minimize() method.